# MySQL 5 doesn't recognize BEFORE?

Tags: sql, mysql, macos

In MySQL 5.0.51b on my Mac, ordinals beyond FIRST fail, as does BEFORE.

So,

```
ALTER TABLE my_contacts
ADD COLUMN phone VARCHAR(10) FOURTH;
```

fails altogether, as would

```
ALTER TABLE my_contacts
ADD COLUMN phone VARCHAR(10) BEFORE email;
```

Do these work with any other flavors or versions of MySQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt they work any differently on other OS installations as the [mysql docs for alter table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/alter-table.html) in 5.0 don't offer a BEFORE modifier. I recommend using AFTER instead (or FIRST if you're inserting this as the first column in the table).

```
ALTER TABLE my_contacts
ADD COLUMN phone VARCHAR(10) AFTER some_column_name;
```

Comment: np... good question. I had to look up the docs myself because, frankly, I would have also sworn that there was a BEFORE modifier :-)